# How to Drag a UIImageView along a Bezier Path

Tags: ios, iphone, c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I am Developing a game in which a `UIImageView` moves along a `Bezier` path. I want to provide user interaction to the moving `UIimageview` so that the user can guide the `UIImageView` by touching the `UIImageView`, and dragging it around the path!  How does one do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use pan gesture and add it to UIImageView and provide your path along which user move it.[Pan Gesture](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)

This link might be helpful in understanding and implementing same. Anything else let me know.

Comment: i want to provide user interaction to the moving UIimageview so that user can guide the UIImageView by touching the UIImageview and drag the UIImageview around a Bezier path.

Comment: So I have provided you with link ,just go through it and see if it work's fine for you. Hope this does else let me know I would find in something else for you

Comment: For that bezier path you should provide it as a big line/rope to user so he/she could know along which path he/she has to move that image.

Comment: Rest I don't have much idea about your game and plot of it.

Comment: i see that link that link is just to move the image around screen i want when user touch the image the image drag and flow a path that is predefined.

Comment: So when pan gesture is detected and function is called then you could check for path and do as per your logic that is to move image or not.

Comment: Also could you provide some idea abut your game ?

Comment: Check this [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006670-SW1) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142727/how-can-i-animate-the-movement-of-a-view-or-image-along-a-curved-path)

Comment: see i add a image i want the user touch the image and image move along the the D letter with user touch not with animations

Comment: Do check out link which I provided above(recent one). Also u want image to move along D letter path(like in D shape) ??

Comment: i already move the image using the animation but i want it that user touch the image when user drag the image the image follow the path and move along the user touch but in the path .if user move outside the path the image does not move

Comment: Use this -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event and in dis before placing your image just check it's point with bezier path point's if match den place image else move it to previous point's.

Comment: So whenever point match's den put that point in previous and check for next point's of image.

Comment: As you draw a bezier path so must be having that points and just cross check it. Also me looking for a alternative for it. So if I come across any then would let u know

Comment: we draw bezier using lines like add line from start to end point

Comment: So you do get the start and end point's then you need to store all points and keep a check for moving of imageView.

Comment: that i dont know to store the points from the bezier path if you have any code or any example please send me

Comment: I don't have example and I'm stuck with other stuff. I find out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058979/find-a-point-a-given-distance-along-a-simple-cubic-bezier-curve-on-an-iphone) might help you out ! hope so...

Comment: Upload your code on github and share the link. Will look into that one where your animating the imageView and try to get in changes you require.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the touch point coordinates are inside Beizer Path. If it is inside allow UITouch and Movement, else not. Give **If Condition** accordingly.

Comment: can you please provide me some code or document how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

Here selectedImageCat is gobal uiimageview object and touchimgView is select(touched) imageview

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        for (UITouch *touchPoint in touches)
        {
              if(CGRectContainsPoint(touchimgView.frame, [touchPoint locationInView:self.view]))
        selectedImageCat=(UIImageView*)touchimgView;

        }
    }

    -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        if (selectedImageCat!=nil)
        {
            CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
            [selectedImageCat setCenter:pt];
        }
    }

    -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {


        //here you provide final frame for touchimgView object
    }
```

Comment: already done it is for the move the image aroung the screen not for selected path