# get point.y in BezierPath with point.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpath

I call 
`- (void)addCurveToPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint controlPoint1:(CGPoint)controlPoint1 controlPoint2:(CGPoint)controlPoint2;` to create a curve path.

can I get every point.y from the path when I provide a point.x ？

Comment: You required equation of the curve you draw?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058979/find-a-point-a-given-distance-along-a-simple-cubic-bezier-curve-on-an-iphone

Comment: Also a bezier curve can have multiple points with the same x coordinate.